# How should "sensei" be formatted when used alone? Capitalising when addressing someone - using their job title, rank or role in place of a name

Tags: word-usage, formatting

Example sentence:

> Thank you, sensei.

Should it be Sensei, sensei, or *sensei*?

I [searched](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22thank%20you%20sensei%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1vYO0g9bXAhWKi7wKHVcxBo0Q_AUIDygA&biw=1897&bih=947) on Google books and I found many versions. (One problem, though, is that I can't see the italics.)

Comment: Since it's a Japanese word for a Japanese cultural concept, my guess is that it's a matter of personal preference or, if it's for publication, house style.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I updated the answer.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to do so? The Japanese almost always address each other by name, especially in formal language. In an academic context, it would be family name-honorific suffix or title. If they’re dealing with the English speaking international community, they’re probably used to being addressed as Doctor or Professor anyway. If you’re dropping formalities, they’d omit names and subjects that are obvious from context. If you really want to be sincere and culturally appropriate use: ありがとうございます。よろしくお願います。

Comment: @TomKelly The setting are two friends. One of them is referring jokingly to him as *sensei*. Because the former is teaching him some stuff.

Comment: In Japanese, 先生 is only used to address teachers or professors. Senpai or Kun between males of a similar age. Otherwise, if you’re borrowing words from Japanese and ignoring the original meaning, then do whatever you like. Just be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be...

> Thank you, Sensei.

...with initial capital, but without *italics*. When addressing someone - using their job title, rank or role *in place of a name* - it's normal to capitalise. So it would be "Thank you, Captain" (or General, Prime Minister, Chief Engineer, etc.). There are more examples of this here: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp (rule 6b)

In general, practitioners of Japanese disciplines in the West use titles like *sensei* or *roshi* in exactly that way - as if *Sensei* were the person's given name, even.

**Exceptions:**

1) If you're talking about a particular sensei, but not addressing them, or *naming* them, there's no need to capitalise. ***"He's sensei at the local dojo"***, is fine.

2) If you want to emphasise the word, you could italicise: **"Thank you, *Sensei*"**.

3) When used in English, sensei has a very deferential/reverential feel, and it's nearly always used as a title. But in Japanese, I understand that it can just mean "a more senior student than myself" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensei ... so it could be appropriate in rare cases to use it *un-capitalised*, as an acknowledgement of the person's relationship to you, rather than as a title... ***"Thank you, sensei"***.

This would be similar to the difference between "*Thank you, Brother*", which you might say to a monk, and, "*Thank you, brother*", which you might say to one of your many siblings.